# PHP: Read XML node value depending on parameter value

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file which contains Spanish and English product description, here's example:

```
<property>
<descriptions>
<description language="es"><text><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum Spanish description]]></text></description>
<description language="en"><text><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum English description]]></text></description>
</descriptions>
</property>
```

I use PHP script to process the XML and import values to the database. Here is how I get the value of the first product description:

```
$Spanish_Description= $property->descriptions->description[0]->text;
```

However, in the XML file for some products Spanish description comes first and for other products it comes second so i can't rely on node order number.

How can I modify my PHP code to specifically look for the value of `<description language="es"></description>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath, or just test for the one you want..

```
$language="en";
foreach ( $property->descriptions->description as $description )    {
    if ( $description['language'] == $language )    {
        echo "For:".$description['language'].'='.$description->text.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$text=$property->xpath("//description[@language='$language']/text")[0];
echo (string)$text;
```

Comment: With using `echo` value implicitly converted into string, there's no need to use `(string)` cast.

Comment: I tend to use it as people don't always want to echo out the value and when used in other circumstances the cast can become important.

Comment: My final version of code:

 `$language="en";
 foreach ( $property->descriptions->description as $description )    {
    if ( $description['language'] == $language )    {
    $English_Description= $description->text;
    }
}`

Comment: i guess in this specific case, it doesn't matter, but you should generally escape your variables, eg $language

Answer (score 0):

This [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) query on the SimpleXML object help a lot with this:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//property[descriptions[description[@language="es"]]]');
$node = $nodes[0];
print_r($node);
```

It allows you to directly access a specific description with the attribute `language="es"`